# I tried to create a small .exe file using pyinstaller but it is showing an error

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.9

I tried to create a small .exe file using pyinstaller but it is showing an error **"The Application has failed to start because it's side-by-side is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool"**

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9IWB.png)

Comment: So did you **see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool** to try to see what the problem might be?

Comment: I don't know how/what to use sxstrace. I just started learning python